# Android Intent Cannot resolve constructor

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Есть боковое всплывающее меню, в нем находится один элемент списка. Когда нажимаем на этот элемент, должна появиться панель `TabHost` и работать с классом `FramgentRankStudent`. Чтобы работать с этим классом, использую `Intent`, но выдает следующую ошибку:

> cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(com.magtu.magtunews.fragments.FragmentEntarnt, java.lang.Class)'

Как решить эту проблему?

Вот часть кода:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_magtu_entrant, container,
            false);

    //Меню свреху имеет три действиея которые описаны ниже.
    TabHost tabs = (TabHost) view.findViewById(R.id.tabHost_entrant);
    tabs.setup();
    //Первый элемент - Раздел Абитуриент список поступающих на бюджетную основу
    TabHost.TabSpec spec_list_budjet = tabs.newTabSpec("List Budjet");
    Intent inboxIntent = new Intent(this, FragmentRankStudent.class);
    spec_list_budjet.setContent(inboxIntent);
    String TabListBudjet = getString(R.string.text_tab_list_budjet);
    spec_list_budjet.setIndicator(TabListBudjet);
    tabs.addTab(spec_list_budjet);
    TextView list_Budject = (TextView) tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    list_Budject.setTextSize(5);
    list_Budject.setMaxLines(1);
    list_Budject.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); 

    return view;
}
```

Делал следующие изменения для исправления этой ошибки:

```
Intent inboxIntent = new Intent(getActivity, FragmentRankStudent.class);
```

и

```
Intent inboxIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), FragmentRankStudent.class);
```

При запуске проекта в Logcat указывает следующие ошибки:

> at com.magtu.magtunews.MagtuNews.onCreate(MagtuNews.java:45) 
>   at com.magtu.magtunews.fragments.FragmentEntrant.onCreateView(FragmentEntrant.java:82)

Если смотреть в коде, то:

> at com.magtu.magtunews.fragments.FragmentEntrant.onCreateView(FragmentEntrant.java:82)

Указывает на `tabs.addTab(spec_list_budjet);`

и

> at com.magtu.magtunews.MagtuNews.onCreate(MagtuNews.java:45)

Указывает на `setContentView(R.layout.activity_magtu_news);`

В классе MagtuNews:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_magtu_news);
    saveInitialConstants(this);
    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (FragmentNavigationDrawer)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();
    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
    s_fragmentRegistration.setTabsChangeListener(this);
    if(null == savedInstanceState)
    {
        hideFragments(s_fragmentEntrant);
        s_fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
    }
}
```

Comment: Intent inboxIntent = new Intent(this, FragmentRankStudent.class); Что конкретно вы хотели сделать этой строчкой? так делать нельзя

Comment: Работать с этим классом, а если быть точным вызвать форму fragment_rank_student.xml

Comment: Фрагменты вызываются не через `Intent`, как активити, а через `FragmentManager`

Comment: Но ведь во FragmentManager в классе MagtuNews вызывается только s_fragmentEntrant, а в самом 
классе FragmentEntarnt вызывается Intent FragmentRankStudent.class

Answer (score 2):

Эта ошибка означает, что вы пытаетесь создать экземпляр класса через конструктор, который не существует. Конкретно в вашем случае вы пытаетесь создать `Intent`, передавая в конструктор неверные типы аргументов. Видимо, вы хотите вызвать конструктор вида `Intent(Context ctx, Class clazz)`, и либо не контекст передаёте первым аргументом или не тот класс - интент может в качестве класса принять только класс, наследующий `Activity/AppCompatActivity`, но не фрагмент.

Судя по всему вы пытаетесь неправильно использовать устаревший `TabHost`, коий работает, вроде, с активити. Скорее всего, вам надо переделать всё под новый `TabLayout`

Comment: Такой вопрос в новом варианте TabLayout нужно использовать  extends AppCompatActivity, а в старом варианте TabHost использовать extends Fragment, я правильно понял.

Тогда следующий вопрос, как сделать правильно в старом варианте если использую extends Fragment?