# Подскажите как прописать кнопку в фрагменте(потому что findViewById не работает)

Tags: java, android

Не могу понять почему ошибку вілазит врорде все правильно

```
package com.example.freebiesir;
    
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
    
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    
    
    /**
     * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
     * Use the {@link BlankFragment1#newInstance} factory method to
     * create an instance of this fragment.
     */
    public class BlankFragment1 extends Fragment {
    
        // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
        // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
        private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
        private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    
    
        private Button skipBtn;
    
    
        // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
        private String mParam1;
        private String mParam2;
    
        public BlankFragment1() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }
    
        /**
         * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
         * this fragment using the provided parameters.
         *
         * @param param1 Parameter 1.
         * @param param2 Parameter 2.
         * @return A new instance of fragment BlankFragment1.
         */
        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        public static BlankFragment1 newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
            BlankFragment1 fragment = new BlankFragment1();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
            args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
            if (getArguments() != null) {
                mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
                mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
            }
    
            skipBtn = (Button) skipBtn.findViewById(R.id.skip1);
    
    
            skipBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent skip = new Intent(BlankFragment1.this, MainActivity2.class);
                    startActivity(skip);
                }
            });
        }
    
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank1, container, false);
        }
    }
```

Ошибка
Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(com.example.freebiesir.BlankFragment1, java.lang.Class<com.example.freebiesir.MainActivity2>)'

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого нужно сделать так (пример):

```
class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment_layout, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_image);
    }
}
```

ну и дальше уже добавлять слушатели и все прочее. Но вообще ошибка у вас говорит немного о другом мне кажется:

```
Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(com.example.freebiesir.BlankFragment1, java.lang.Class<com.example.freebiesir.MainActivity2>)'
```

проще говоря: `программа не может распознать конструктор`

Вам нужно здесь:

```
Intent skip = new Intent(BlankFragment1.this, MainActivity2.class);
startActivity(skip);
```

вместо:

```
BlankFragment1.this
```

сделать так:

```
getActivity()
```

потому что конструктор ищется такой:

```
Intent(Context ctx, Class clazz)
```

в итоге будет:

```
Intent skip = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity2.class);
startActivity(skip);
```

вот есть подобные вопросы: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/548153/android-intent-cannot-resolve-constructor) и [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46047979/cannot-resolve-constructor-intent)